# Issue with Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting error below:

> "ORA-00904: "MESSAGE_BODY": invalid identifier"

When I run below query against an Oracle database?

```
SELECT COMMERCIAL_ID, MIN(dbms_lob.substr(MESSAGE_BODY, 3999, 1)) AS MESSAGE_BODY
FROM DWH_F_MP_MESSAGE_VW
GROUP BY COMMERCIAL_ID;
```

> MESSAGE_BODY field is a CLOB

Comment: Take a closer look at the orphaned quotation mark at the end of the first line.

Comment: that was just a typo when I was entering to SO....thats not the problem.  Ive edited accordingly; thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `DWH_F_MP_MESSAGE_VW` doesn't contain a column named `MESSAGE_BODY`.

Here's a demonstration:

```
SQL> create table dwh_f_mp_message_vw (commercial_id number, message_body clob);

Table created.

SQL> insert into dwh_f_mp_message_vw values (1, 'Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> select commercial_id, min(dbms_lob.substr(message_body, 3999, 1))
  2  from dwh_f_mp_message_vw
  3  group by commercial_id;

COMMERCIAL_ID
-------------
MIN(DBMS_LOB.SUBSTR(MESSAGE_BODY,3999,1))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
            1
Littlefoot


SQL> select commercial_id, min(dbms_lob.substr(message_bodyyyyyy, 3999, 1))
  2  from dwh_f_mp_message_vw
  3  group by commercial_id;
select commercial_id, min(dbms_lob.substr(message_bodyyyyyy, 3999, 1))
                                          *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "MESSAGE_BODYYYYYY": invalid identifier


SQL>
```

I suggest you run this:

```
SQL> desc dwh_f_mp_message_vw
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------
 COMMERCIAL_ID                                      NUMBER
 MESSAGE_BODY                                       CLOB
```

and post the result back here (unless you figure it out; in that case, please, explain what went wrong). A possible culprit is a column created under double quotes, e.g.

```
SQL> drop table dwh_f_mp_message_vw;

Table dropped.

SQL> create table dwh_f_mp_message_vw (commercial_id number, "message_body" clob);

Table created.

SQL> insert into dwh_f_mp_message_vw (commercial_id, message_body) values (1, 'Littlefoot');
insert into dwh_f_mp_message_vw (commercial_id, message_body) values (1, 'Littlefoot')
                                                *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00904: "MESSAGE_BODY": invalid identifier


SQL> insert into dwh_f_mp_message_vw (commercial_id, "message_body") values (1, 'Littlefoot');

1 row created.

SQL> desc dwh_f_mp_message_vw
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- -------------------
 COMMERCIAL_ID                                      NUMBER
 message_body                                       CLOB

SQL>
```

If that's so, get rid of double quotes.

Comment: You were right...field was present in original base table but was missing from view.....thanks